# Expansion of $f(x)=\frac {\ln(1+\sin ax)-x(1+\arctan x)^{1/x}}{1-\cos x} $ for $x$ near $0$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

How to find finite expansion of $$f(x)=\frac {\ln(1+\sin(ax))-x(1+\arctan x)^{1/x}}{1-\cos x} $$ to order $2$ and neighborhood $0$. My Dr. didn't expand them all to order $2$, please I have problem understanding the orders.

Comment: One way to do that involves finding the first and second derivatives of your function at $x=0$. Can you do that?

Comment: Yes I know that but what worries me is the order. How to know how to expand each of my terms in the numerator and the denominator to get an overall of order 2? @RoryDaulton

Comment: If you can find the first and second derivatives of the overall function at $x=0$ there is no need to expand any part of the function. Just use $f(0)+f'(0)x+\frac{f''(0)}{2}x^2$ as your order-two Taylor expansion. There probably are other ways to solve your problem that use the expansions of part of the function, but you should go with the method you know you can do.

Comment: Sometimes the big function gets very complicated and my problem is how to decide what order each term must be expanded into in order for the over all function gets the desired order.... @RoryDaulton

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may write, **for $x$ near $0$**,
$$
1-\cos x=\frac{x^2}{2}+\mathcal{O}(x^3)
$$
$$
\sin ax=ax-\frac{a^3x^3}{6}+\mathcal{O}(x^5)
$$
$$
\log(1+\sin ax)=ax-\frac{a^2x^2}{2}+\mathcal{O}(x^3)
$$
$$
\arctan x=x-\frac{x^3}{3}+\mathcal{O}(x^5)
$$ 
$$
\frac1x\log(1+\arctan x)=1-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^3}{12}+\mathcal{O}(x^4)
$$ then
$$
(1+\arctan x)^{1/x}=e^{\frac1x\log(1+\arctan x)}=e^{1-\frac{x}{2}+\mathcal{O}(x^2)}=e(1-\frac{x}{2}+\mathcal{O}(x^2))
$$ and
$$
f(x)=\frac {\ln(1+\sin ax)-x(1+\arctan x)^{1/x}}{1-\cos x}=\frac{ax-\frac{a^2x^2}{2}-ex(1-\frac{x}{2})+\mathcal{O}(x^3)}{x^2/2+\mathcal{O}(x^3)}
$$ giving the Laurent expansion $$ \frac{2(a-e)}{x}+e-a^2+\mathcal{O}(x) $$ for $f(x)$, $x$ being near $0$.

Comment: Thank youuuuuuuuuuuuu. You rock!